# ionic capacitor Filesystem writeFile API throwing error

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to take a picture from camera and save it in the filesystem. I am using aweseom-cordova-plugins, camera-preview plugin. I am able to take the picture successfully and display it in the UI successfully. But I am not able to save it the filesystem. My physical device is an android device.

```
import { CameraPreview, CameraPreviewPictureOptions, CameraPreviewOptions, CameraPreviewDimensions } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/camera-preview/ngx';
```

.
.
.
//

```
 const cameraPreviewOpts: CameraPreviewOptions = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      width: window.screen.width,
      height: window.screen.height,
      camera: 'rear',
      tapPhoto: true,
      tapFocus :true,
      previewDrag: true,
      toBack: true,
      alpha: 1,
      storeToFile: false,
    }

// start camera
    this.cameraPreview.startCamera(cameraPreviewOpts).then(
      (res) => {

        this.cameraActive =true;


        console.log("Camera started " + res)
        // picture options
        const pictureOpts: CameraPreviewPictureOptions = {
          width: 1280,
          height: 1280,
          quality: 85
        }

        // take a picture
        this.cameraPreview.takePicture(pictureOpts).then((base64Imagedata) => {
          console.log("picture taken");
          this.image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64Imagedata;
          this.savePicture(base64Imagedata);
          console.log("now closing the camera");
          this.cameraPreview.stopCamera().then(
            res =>{this.cameraActive =false},
            err =>{console.error("error while closing the camera"+err)}
          );
        }, (err) => {
          console.log("error while taking the pic"+err);
          this.image = 'assets/img/test.jpg';
        });
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err)
      });
```

.
.
.

And this is my savePicture method, which is throwing the below error

```
    import { Filesystem, Directory } from '@capacitor/filesystem';

     private async savePicture(base64Imagedata : any) {
       
        console.log("base 64 image data is "+base64Imagedata)
        
        console.log("goign to save the pciture to file")
console.log("Data directory full path is "+ Directory.Data);
        // Write the file to the data directory
        const fileName = new Date().getTime() + '.jpeg';
        const savedFile = await Filesystem.writeFile({
          path: fileName,
          data: base64Imagedata,
          directory: Directory.Data
        });
        console.log("goign to save the pciture to file")
       
      }
```

FileSystem.writeFile is throwing the below error

```
    vendor.js:70616 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NO_DATA
Error: NO_DATA
    at returnResult (VM3:744:32)
    at win.androidBridge.onmessage (VM3:719:21)
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:1643:21)
    at polyfills.js:1538:11
    at polyfills.js:1555:27
    at rejected (vendor.js:24941:89)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (polyfills.js:570:160)
    at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:92209:25)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (polyfills.js:570:48)
    at Zone.run (polyfills.js:296:37)
    at polyfills.js:1716:28
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:603:173)
```

I am using capacitor filesystem plugin.
Can someone please help?

One sample run of base64ImageData is logged as below

```
base 64 image data is `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`
```

And output of full Data directory from console.log is (taken from android studio console )

```
I/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/src_app_tab3_tab3_module_ts.js - Line 76 - Msg: Data directory full path is DATA
```

Comment: A preview is only a thumbnail. Are you trying to save that thumbnail? Why not take a full size picture?

Comment: `path: fileName,` Only a file name? You do not specify a directory using a full path? Do you know in which directory the file would land if you only specify a file name?

Comment: @blackapps there are two methods in the CameraPreview, one is takePicture other is takeSnapshot. I think what you meant is takesSnapShot
https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview

Comment: `Error: NO_DATA
Error: NO_DATA`

Comment: @blackapps I am also passing the directory
 directory: Directory.Data
Not sure what went wrong.

Comment: Ok. sorry, did not see that. Well then tell full path of that directory. Also show and tell us where and when and how you call savePicture(). We should know the parameter value you use.

Comment: It is there in the first snippet
 this.savePicture(base64Imagedata);

Comment: `I think what you meant is takesSnapShot` I mean nothing. I asked you if you only got a thumbnail. And if true then why not a full size picture. Answer please.

Comment: @blackapps tbh , i cant say for sure if its a thumbnail or actual pic. I am only able to see it in the UI, not able to check its size etc. (had i saved it as a file, i could say for sure)

Comment: What is the length of that `base64Imagedata` string? That will give an indication.

Comment: i had debugged it in chrome externally, I can see that all three values in writeFile call are present , path, data and directory.
I will update the base64 data logging also in the question now

Comment: Please telll full path of directory. (Second time i ask).

Comment: @blackapps the Directory is a capcitor abstraction of filesystem. It has some default enums. Directory. Data on android refers to data directory which usually I can see in "internal storage =>android=>data==><APP ID>==>files

Comment: /**
     * The Data directory
     * On iOS it will use the Documents directory.
     * On Android it's the directory holding application files.
     * Files will be deleted when the application is uninstalled.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    Data = "DATA",

Comment: It can never be 'DATA'.  And if so it was not usable. `console.log(Directory.Data)` would tell you and me the full path i asked for.

Comment: @blackapps Just added those details to the question, It indeed is "DATA"

Comment: Sorry, i cannot help you with that DATA directory. Well if that is the problem...  Please try other available  directories of the capcitor abstraction of filesystem.